# Issue working with partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial-views

I am using rails 3.1. I have a view `products/show.html.erb` and I call a partial like this

```
<%= render 'productrelationships/relatedproduct',:collection => @product.relatedproducts %>
```

and i access it in this way inside my partial (`productrelationship/_relatedproduct`)

```
<% logger.error 'Related Products ' + relatedproduct.inspect %>
```

The inspect returns a nil. But if I try the same inside my show.html.erb, it is not nil. There is some mistake in passing the value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. It started working when i added `:partial` while rendering

```
<%= render :partial => 'productrelationships/relatedproduct',:collection => @product.relatedproducts %>
```

Comment: As you discovered, when rendering with `:collection` you must explicitly specify `:partial`. If you simply call `render "x", :collection => "y"` your passing a single variable called `:collection` as part of your `:locals` to the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the local variable.

```
<%= render :partial => 'productrelationships/relatedproduct',
           :collection => @product.relatedproducts,
           :as => :relatedproduct %>
```